# Least squares assuming functional form of the solution

Tags: matlab, least-squares

I am trying to solve the following least squares problem:

b(alpha)=A(alpha,beta)x(beta)

I am trying to use an alternative approach, which is to assume the functional form of x(beta) through the use of tunable parameters, say x(beta, a, c). How can I solve this problem in MATLAB for a least squares solution for those parameters?

Comment: 1) [edit] to properly format your post. Note how Latex is not supported. 2) Show a [mcve]. The fact that your result is not good is irrelevant if you dont tell us how you got the result!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow! As Ander says, you need to show us what you tried already and what didn't work. Post some of your code that we can run ourselves.

Comment: And if you can't post code you've tried (because you haven't tried anything), then *at least* show a concrete mathematical example with reproducible inputs and expected outputs. Without either, this is currently too broad and as such I'm flagging to close it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I second the comments -this would be much easier if you gave a slightly more verbose description of your problem and most importantly add a minimal working example.

As far as I understand though, you want to solve a [linear system of equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/System_of_linear_equations) with some additional assumptions about the fitted parameters. This can be done by expressing them as [an optimisation problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optimization_problem).

Here for example I've fitted a quadratic where the coefficients of `x^0` and `x^1` are both dependant on some other arbitrary parameter `a` (for this example a = 6 - that's what we're trying to recover from the data).

[image: constrainedQuadFitting]

There are 2 different approaches plotted here - unconstrained and constrained optimisation. You can see that all of them approximate our data well, but only the constrained optimisation recovers a value of a close to 6 (5.728). Anyway, have a look at the code and I hope this helps with your problem somewhat. If you can, try to use the reduced number of parameters approach. It is always better to reduce your fitting problems to lower dimensional spaces if possible - much less risk of local minima and much faster solutions.

Here is the code:

```
close all; clear; clc;

%% Generate test data
x = 1:100;

rng(0); % Seed rng

% Polynomial where we know something about the parameters - we know that if
% the coefficient of x^0 is 'a'm then the coefficient of x^1 is (1-a).
a = 6;
y = a + (1-a).*x + 0.1*x.^2;
y = y + 30*randn(size(x)); % Add some noise

%% Fit with mrdivide and Vandermonde matrix 
A = vander(x); A = A(:,end-2:end)';
b = y;
k1 = b/A;

%% Fit with an unconstrained optimiser
f = @(k) optimfun1(x,y,k);
k0 = [1 1 1]; % Starting point
k2 = fminsearch(f,k0);

%% Fit with a constrained optimiser
f = @(k) optimfun1(x,y,k);
k0 = [1 1 1]; 
Aeq = [0 1 1]; beq = 1; % Constrain k2 = 1 - k3 which is equivalent to k2+k3 = 1
k3 = fmincon(f,k0,[],[],Aeq,beq);

%% Fit with a reduced number of parameters
f = @(k) optimfun2(x,y,k);
k0 = [1 1]; 
k4 = fminsearch(f,k0);
k4 = [k4 1-k4(2)]; % Infer the last coeff.

%% Plot
plot(x,y,'ko');
hold on
plot(x,polyval(k1,x));
plot(x,polyval(k2,x));
plot(x,polyval(k3,x));
plot(x,polyval(k4,x));
legend('k^{dat} = [6.000 -5.000 0.100];',...
    sprintf('k^{unc}_1 = [%.3f %.3f %.3f]',flipud(k1(:))),...
    sprintf('k^{unc}_2 = [%.3f %.3f %.3f]',flipud(k2(:))),...
    sprintf('k^{cns}_1 = [%.3f %.3f %.3f]',flipud(k3(:))),...
    sprintf('k^{cns}_2 = [%.3f %.3f %.3f]',flipud(k4(:))),...
    'location','northwest');
grid on;
xlabel('x');
ylabel('f(x)');
title(sprintf('f(x) = a + (1-a)x + 0.1x^2; a = %d',a));
```

---

```
function diff = optimfun1(x,y,k)
yfit = polyval(k,x);
dy = yfit-y;
diff = sum(dy.^2); % Sum of squared residuals
end
```

---

```
function diff = optimfun2(x,y,k)
k = [k 1-k(2)]; % Infer the last coeff.
yfit = polyval(k,x);
dy = yfit-y;
diff = sum(dy.^2);
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing exactly how does the parameter works, it is difficult to figure out what to do.  For example if the parameter is

```
x(beta, a, c) = a * x(beta) + c
```

Then your equation becomes

```
b(alpha)= A(alpha,beta) * (a * x(beta) + c)
b(alpha) - c*A(alpha,beta) = A(alpha,beta) * a * x(beta)
```

which then perhaps you can solve in the standard way (I'm treating b and A as numbers and x as the only variable here disregarding the alpha and beta).  For more non-linear relation, it gets complex.